# Table of contents in black. Cross references and bibliography references in blue

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, cross-referencing

I am using `article` as document class and `chicago` as bibliographystyle.

I want to display the table of contents in black (still being able to click on the sections and subsections) and the cross references and bibliography references in blue.

I have considered a few options/packages, but I am not sure which one to use (and which one works):

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\hypersetup{}
```

Help! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` for the table of contents by

```
{\hypersetup{hidelinks}\tableofcontents}
```

or

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents

\section{Test}\label{test} 
Reference to section \ref{test} and a link to \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{document}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\tablename{Chart}
\begin{longtable}{l}
\hline
Test\\
\hline
\caption{Tabla de actividades}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```